# Conveying 'a whole different animal'

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/different%20animal

> Definition of different animal
> : something different

> The sport has changed. It's a very/completely different animal today.

The other day I wanted to say

> Real analysis is **an entirely different animal** from calculus or even linear algebra.

Can one use in French the one-to-one translation

> L'analyse réelle est **un animal totalement différent** du calcul différentiel et intégral ou même de l'algèbre linéaire.

of **an entirely different animal**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you say *un animal totalement différent* in this context, people will stare at you.

If you look for an idiom with a similar meaning, you might use ***[une autre paire de manches](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/c%E2%80%99est_une_autre_paire_de_manches)***:

> L'analyse réelle, c'est une autre paire de manches que le calcul différentiel et intégral ou même l'algèbre linéaire.

Otherwise:

> L'analyse réelle, c'est carrément autre chose que le calcul différentiel et intégral ou même l'algèbre linéaire.

Comment: Selon moi "une autre paire de manches" implique une difficulté supplémentaire mais il semble effectivement que cela puisse être employé sans cette condition. Je pense cependant que la deuxième proposition est plus applicable dans l'exemple donné dans la question.

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui, l'expression s'est en effet spécialisée pour désigner quelque chose de plus difficile plutôt que seulement différent. On ne dira guère: *Traverser l'Atlantique à la nage, c'est un exploit, mais traverser la manche à la nage, c'est une autre paire de manches...* ;-)

Comment: Je note que deepl se contente du mot à mot, donc on va le retrouver dans bien des traductions haahahhah. J'ai passé un texte entier dans deepl dernièrement et c'est le traducteur qui donne la meilleure impression de ne pas avoir fait d'erreur, mais quand on y regarde de plus près, qu'est-ce qu'on rit.

Comment: @20goto10 Oui, réussir une traduction parfaite, c'est une *different pair of sleeves...*

Comment: En effet, je dirais que déguster une bouillabaisse aux poissons à l'aide d'un casse-noisette est plus facile...

Comment: @20goto10 Pas grave, je ne suis pas du tout allergique aux pléonasmes...

Comment: Heureusement, parce que ça va se faire en deux manches...